# Sending form data to restful web service @POST method using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have looked everywhere for hours and cannot find a solution that will work for me. I have a simple html form that gets 3 form inputs and needs to send the data to the @POST method of a web service. After creation, the web service will show the updated list. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

poll.html

```
    <script>

    function myFunction()
    {
        data = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax({
            url:         'http://localhost:8080/places3/resourcesC/create',
            method:      'POST',
            dataType:    'text',
            data:       data,
            success:        function() { alert("Worked"); },
            error:      function(error) { alert("Error"); }
        });
    }

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="myFunction()">

        <p>City: <input type="text" name="city" /> </p>
        <p>POI1: <input type="text" name="poi1" /> </p>
        <p>POI2: <input type="text" name="poi2" /> </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


    </form>
```

@POST method of web service

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/create")
public Response create(@FormParam("city") String city, 
           @FormParam("poi1") String poi1,
        @FormParam("poi2") String poi2) {
checkContext();
String msg = null;
// Require both properties to create.
if (city == null || poi1 == null || poi2 == null) {
    msg = "Property 'city' or 'poi1' or 'poi2' is missing.\n";
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).
                                       entity(msg).
                                       type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).
                                       build();
}       
// Otherwise, create the Place and add it to the collection.
int id = addPlace(city, poi1, poi2);
msg = "Place " + id + " created: (city = " + city + " poi1 = " + poi1 + " poi2 = " + poi2 + ").\n";
return Response.ok(msg, "text/plain").build();
}
```

Comment: What currently happens? Does the success or error functions fire? Any errors in the console?

Comment: It shouldn't alert Error. It should submit the form before the Ajax request resolves.

Comment: It alerts "Error" and does nothing but the url does get the string

Comment: localhost:8080/ajax/?city=flint&poi1=UofM&poi2=MottCC

Comment: try to get some better info from the error. Something like `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log('jqXHR.status: " + jqHR.status); console.log('textStatus: " + textStatus); console.log('errorThrown: " + errorThrown); }`

Comment: Here are the two errors that printed out from adding your code:
1. "Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector."  2. "Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid selector."

Answer (score 0):

I would try giving the form a name such as myform then in your jquery something like:

var data = $("#myform").serializeArray();

Then pass the data var in the ajax command.

This works perfectly for me.